# How can I access my computer remotely?

Tags: 11.10, remote-access

I certainly know of the Remote Desktop app in Ubuntu, but I have never really bothered with accessing my notebook remotely. What is a complete step-by-step guide to accessing my notebook remotely?

Other recommended applications will also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of access is needed? File access, a shared desktop or a remote GUI login? Do you connect from an Ubuntu machine to your notebook?

Comment: How about a full system control? I intend to remotely use my notebook in the house from my workplace using Ubuntu and sometimes, if possible, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an easy solution that work out-of-the-box, without router configuration, you should try dedicated applications like:

- [TeamViewer 6](http://www.teamviewer.com/)
- [Mikogo 4](http://www.mikogo.com/)

There are many other similar apps, but works only on Windows or Mac (like the famous LogMeIn).

Answer (score 5):

To have GUI Access and full control (Graphical Way) you can use **VINO** and **VINAGRE** which come with Ubuntu (LoL I was going to type wine instead of Ubuntu. Don't know why I got confused ^^). Anyway first configure vino which is a vnc server.

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `vino-preferences`
2. Configure it as you like. It will then show you your IP (Assuming is an internet IP). Remember to put a password.
3. Go to the client computer which you will use to connect and open vinagre (Typing vinagre in the command windows or looking for it in the menu as Remote Desktop Viewer)
4. Click on connect and type the IP from your VNC server.

Done.

Now for this to work some points need to be checked, for example:

- Is the IP of the VNC server accessible from the internet (Not a LAN IP)
- Is the router/modem/switch/isp/godzilla connection you have support connections from the outside.
- Do you have good connection to the laptop (Since VNC uses several times more bandwidth than for example ssh.)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded remmina remote from the software channel. I'm running 11.10 on an old laptop.  Not only did I have no problems connecting.  I can now connect to other remote windows servers that are remotely set up through my work PC. Awesome!